# rails 3: clarification needed on which controllers are needed for HABTM relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I've read through a lot of the documentation and for some reason this still isn't clear to me.

I have the following setup, a User table, an Event table, and a M2M table Events_Users defined through HABTM relationships on both Users and Events. When a User signs up for an Event on the Event Index or Show page, should it go to the New action in a controller created for Events_Users? If so, should it go to the New action which only serves to pass the parameters to the Create action? Or should it go straight to the Create action?

Any clarification on best practices would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that one way to do it could be the following:

I would accept the event to have the user as a nested resource this way:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :users
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :events 
end
```

This way you can define a custom action inside the EventsController like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def add_user_to_event
    @event = Event.find(params[:event])
    @user = User.find(params[:user])
    @event.users << @user
    @event.save
  end
end
```

And in your form you would have a link_to this action with the current event and the user as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, so if I add this functionality to the EventsController what happens when I need to reference it from another object? How do I decide to put it on the EventsController instead of the UsersController? or even a unique controller EventsUsersController? thats where I'm getting confused

Comment: Having this action defined in the user controller only points you to define a route named /events/add_user_to_event. You should be able to call this route from wherever you like.

I think that the alternatives you are mentioning are just a matter of preference: Do you add an event from a user view or from the event view? It's up to you. You could even define another action call add_event_to_user under UsersController that does the opposite.

Comment: Hm so there's really no best practice on this stuff? I feel like it has to come up a lot.